# wget ошибка, не удалось проверить сертификат

Tags: wget

Есть ли вариант обойти? <CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US>:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. 2. [mcve] 3. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Используйте флаг --no-check-certificate

Comment: Добавьте --no-check-certificate в команду

Comment: --no-check-certificate использовал, не работает

Comment: Обновить wget или использовать wget2

Comment: Установил wget2, проблема не ушла

Comment: Может, [это](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075780/wget-fails-by-a-certificate-problem)?